# ardrone goes through the mobile robot after changing the stl file

Tags: ros, gazebo, mobile-base, stl, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two robots an AR. Drone and mobile robot. the aim is that the ardrone should see the mobile robot as an obstacle from its laser data. All of the work is in gazebo simulator.

Since the ardrone is flying, I changed the stl file for the mobile robot. I made the robot very long so it acts as a moving wall in order for the ardrone to sense it. now the problem is that the ardrone goes through the mobile robot and it cant sence it ??

how can I fix that??? also any suggestion of dynamic obstacles package ?? I want some thing like a wall moving  ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193359/ardrone-goes-through-the-mobile-robot-after-changing-the-stl-file/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem.
When changing the look of the robot and make it tall in the stl file, I had to change in the both the origin of the base link and origin of the collision tag  and to make it as long as the one I change in the shape.
This is changed form the launch file of the robot urdf file description.

I didn't find any package that do that so, I had to create my own.

what I did it something like a moving wall

---

Originally posted by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) with karma: 275 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0